# UIKit.h mysteriously emptied

Tags: xcode, uiview, uikit, missing-data

Something weird is happening. Using XCode 8.2.1.

All of a sudden the file `UIKit.h` in the iOS10.2 framework is **emptied**. The file is there but empty. So many project class became error because they cant even find `UIImage` and so on.

Yesterday it happened to my colleague where his UIView.h is being emptied. So I copied my file and gave to him. Today it is my turn with the UIkit.h being emptied. WTF?

Where can I find the original `UIkit.h`? Also as I check further, I can modify any of the apple's standard class files. I thought Apple supposed to make these "read only"?

Comment: you could always simply re-install XCode 8.2.1, which would bring your SDK & files back.

Comment: That could work but with the size more than 10GB to redownload, really like swatting flies with a sledgehammer..